# "bubble" 's possible new meaning in English

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence:

> And I shall carry on with the 40 hour week working with people who are in more bubbles than a bloody aero !!

This is a top up-voted comment from the comment section of this Daily Mail article "[No stopping for a chat if you bump into friends, and DON'T sit on park benches: Chris Whitty and ministers warn against 'pushing boundaries' of lockdown with NHS on the brink of disaster - and the rules could get even TOUGHER](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-9133439/Chris-Whitty-delivers-stark-warning-NHS-threat-surging-Covid.html)"

Many describe this comment as "Brilliant", "Love it, so true. Thank you for the chuckle", "This should be top comment haha" ,"Brilliant! Great comment".

I can't get the humor of the comment.

I think the catch is the word "bubble" which may have gained some new meanings lately. Every entry of "bubble" in the [dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bubble) doesn't fit.

Comment: Your profile doesn't say where you are, but the UK government has coined the word 'bubble' to mean a group of people who may meet together during the pandemic. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/making-a-support-bubble-with-another-household

Comment: [Oxford has a better definition](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/bubble_1?q=bubble) *a small group of people with whom you are allowed to have physical contact during a period when social distancing is otherwise required*. It’s always a good idea to check more than one dictionary. There are some dictionary recommendations on [meta] https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4721/what-sorts-of-dictionaries-should-we-use-on-ell

Comment: In the Wikipedia definition, it's No. 15!

Comment: It's a deliberately "quirky" usage. Not least because it reverses the imagery of ***people in bubbles*** by invoking an image of ***Aeros** in bubbles* ("Aero" candy bars ***contain*** bubbles, not the other way around). Reminds me of *Spring is sprung! The grass is riz! I wonder where them birdies is. The little birds is on the wing. Ain't that absurd! **The wings is on the little birds**!* (delivered in a Bronx accent, with ***boids, absoid***, etc.).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica  I think it is more likely that this was a clumsy attempt to link an old trope "more bubbles than an Aero" with the new one, of people "having" "Covid bubbles".

Comment: @MikeBrockington: You might well be right. Personally, I thought it was quite an amusing turn of phrase (and I agree with the implied exasperated tone), so I'm inclined to give the writer the benefit of the doubt. Anyway, despite being essentially a "post-modernist" (it's irrelevant what the writer *intended*, since "the text is all"), I generally think it makes more sense to assume people do actually know what they're saying/writing, and *usually* they know how to express themselves (learners excepted, of course! :)

Comment: People who write below-the-line comments on _Daily Mail_ articles are often very close to being imbeciles, and so are the people who vote for them. The _Mail_ is a notorious right-wing British tabloid.

Answer (score 5):

"Bubble" hasn't gained a new meaning as such, but in the context of the Covid-19 pandemic, the UK Government has started to refer to a small group of people (in some cases) as "a bubble". The basic principle is that if you have two people, who live in different houses, they can 'pretend' that they live in the same household, and therefore isolate from everyone else, with the exception of each other.

In some cases, it seems that certain people redefine their particular bubble very frequently, which is contrary to the original intention, and therefore such a person could be said to belong to 'many bubbles'.

The other part of the allusion, is to a popular chocolate bar, which is marketed largely on containing loads (millions?) of bubbles, which long ago started to lead to numerous comparisons containing the phrase "more bubbles than an Aero".